# Showing Type error int object is not subscriptable in the rat in a maze problem that I tried to solved using python

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, backtracking

> this is my code for solving rat in a maze problem i was trying my logic using canmoveforward and canmovedown function but getting type error that int object is not subscriptable I am not getting it why it is showing error

```
puzzle=[[1,0,0,0],
   [1,1,0,1],
   [0,1,0,0],
   [0,1,1,1]]


sol=[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0]]      
N=4;
def canforward(x,y,arr,N):
  if x==y==N:
    return False
  else:
    for i in range(x+1,N):
      if arr[i][y]==1:
        return True
      return False

def canmovedown(x,y,arr,N):
  if x==y==N:
    return False
  else:
    for i in range(y+1,N):
      if arr[x][i]==1:
        return True
      return False

 def runrat(x,y,arr):
    if x==y==N:
      print(sol)
      return True
    else:
      if canforward(x,y,arr,N):
        sol[x+1][y]=1
        if runrat(x+1,y,N):
          return True
      else:
        sol[x+1][y]=0
        return False
   elif canmovedown(x,y,arr,N):
       sol[x][y+1]=1
       if runrat(x,y+1,N):
          return True
       else:
          sol[x][y+1]=0
          return False
   else:
      return False


 runrat(0,0,puzzle)
 print(sol)
```

Comment: share the error

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong, for the `runrat` function, the condition levels inside is "if, else, elif"? Please check your code and site properly.

Answer (score 0):

Once you clean up the indentation:

```
N=4;
...
 def runrat(x,y,arr):
...
        if runrat(x+1,y,N):
...
       if runrat(x,y+1,N):
```

The `runrat` function expects a list of lists as its third parameter `arr`, but you are passing it `N`, an integer.  I believe this is why you are getting the "int object is not subscriptable" error.